# List item repeating in android customized listview

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

In my customized list view items are repeating.position of item is same for all item.
code is below

ListAdapter.java-

```
    public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<String> mName;
private List<Drawable> mIcon;
private Context mContext;

public ListAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> Name, List<Drawable> Icon) {
    this.mContext=mContext;
    this.mName=Name;
    this.mIcon=Icon;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    View mLayout;
    TextView mText;
    ImageView mImage;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;

    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mLayout=new View(mContext);
        mLayout=(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null);

        mText=(TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        mImage=(ImageView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.Icon);
        mCheckBox=(CheckBox) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.mCheckbox);

        mText.setText(mName.get(position));
        mImage.setImageDrawable(mIcon.get(position));

        mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton check, boolean isChecked) {
                if(check.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "..."+mName.get(position)+"..."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }   
    else{
        mLayout=(View)v;
    }
    return mLayout;
}

  }
```

Comment: so what is exactly the question?

Comment: listview items get repeating.suppose A,B,C,D are list items then it shows A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this one, You need to `setTag()` for each convertview.

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();

        mHolder.mText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
        mHolder.mImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
        mHolder.mCheckBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mCheckbox);

        convertView.setTag(mHolder);

    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private TextView mText;
    private ImageView mImage;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;

}
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html. its  view holder not only setTag. and view holder must be static  why is view holder final?

Comment: I almoust eat my teeth on it. Thank you, now i can go sleep;p

Answer (score 1):

Change your getView

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mLayout=new View(mContext);
    mLayout=(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null);
```

Initialize inflater in your constructor. Remove this `mLayout=new View(mContext)` coz you are inflating a layout with `mLayout=(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null)`

In your constructor

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
public ListAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> Name, List<Drawable> Icon) {
this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
this.mContext=mContext;
this.mName=Name;
this.mIcon=Icon;
}
```

Use a View holder for smooth scrolling and performance.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh;
    if(convertView==null){
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        convertView =(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null);

        vh.mText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        vh.mImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Icon);
        vh.mCheckBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mCheckbox);

        convertView.setTag(vh); 
    } else { 
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    } 

    vh.mText.setText(mName.get(position));
    vh.mImage.setImageDrawable(mIcon.get(position));
    vh.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton check, boolean isChecked) {
            if(check.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "..."+mName.get(position)+"..."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView mText;
    ImageView mImage;
    CheckBox mCheckBox;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<String> mName;
        private List<Drawable> mIcon;
        private Context mContext;

        public ListAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> Name, List<Drawable> Icon) {
            this.mContext=mContext;
            this.mName=Name;
            this.mIcon=Icon;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mName.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if(v==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v =(LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, null);

                holder.mText=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Name);
                holder.mImage=(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Icon);
                holder.mCheckBox=(CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.mCheckbox);

              v.setTag(holder);
            }
            else{
               holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            holder.mText.setText(mName.get(position));
            holder.mImage.setImageDrawable(mIcon.get(position));

            holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton check, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(check.isChecked()){
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "..."+mName.get(position)+"..."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            v.setTag(holder);
            return v;
        }

         class ViewHolder{
            TextView mText;
            ImageView mImage;
            CheckBox mCheckBox;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `v.setTag(holder);` in your `if(v==null)` statement will cause NPE.

Comment: @Shubham,Please check my updated ans and thanks for highlighting it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the convertView is not null. Hence place all code after the if(convertView == null){ 
} which ensures you have a convertView whose value is not null, by inflating from context if so.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_menu, parent, false);
  } 

  TextView mText=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
  ImageView mImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
  CheckBox mCheckBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mCheckbox);

  mText.setText(mName.get(position));
  mImage.setImageDrawable(mIcon.get(position));

  return convertView;
}
```

Comment: contextView should not be null. Thus finding views after if(convertView == null){} will resolve the issue.